# Get row index of most recent non-blank cell in adjacent column (Excel)

Tags: excel

In an Excel spreadsheet I have Column A with some text spaced out by blank cells. I want in Column B to return the row index of the nearest non-blank cell in Column A (from above only).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in B1 and fill down.

```
=match("zzz", a$1:a1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following on the second row after manually putting the row number for the first row:

```
=IF(A2="",B1,ROW(B2))
```

[image]